# Java code for composition

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

Is it possible to implement composition in Java?
If we create a class A and use an instance of this class in class B, then how can we ensure that A cannot create an independent object by itself?

Comment: so based on the replies that i am getting i can safely conclude that it is not possible to implement composition in Java except through the use of inner class (which is way too obvious). Therefore a third party class can never be included as composition.

Comment: If you have a third party class for which you "cannot create an independent object", how can you use it in composition?

Comment: @AmitKhanna: Of course i can create an object of the third party class. I just want to confirm that the third party class can never be used in composition (whether i can make an object of it or not).

Comment: Why do the replies mean that it is not possible to implement composition in Java?  Even if an instance of class A can be created outside of B how does that violate composition?

Comment: Aggregation - referenced object can live on it own, composition - object cannot live outside of its parent. E.g. you can agregate glasses and be composed of two hands.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert: It violates composition because in composition the child object cannot exist without the parent object.

Comment: @qualtar I don't think it is necessary to enforce that an instance of A cannot be created outside of B.  It can certainly useful, in some scenarios, but it is also possible for A to be used as a part of another class aside from B.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert: if A can exist without B then it would not be composition it would simply be aggregation. The object of A has to die if the object of B dies to qualify the relationship as composition.

Comment: @qualtar Would it solve your problem if A was a package-protected class in the same package as B?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert: No. See, my point is that the object of A MUST die when object of B dies. Even for a package protected class the object of A can be used in other classes of the same package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible. The only similar solution is to create A as private inner class of B. Then nobody else than B can instantiate A.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your composed classes as an inner class of your container class.

```
class ContainerClass{

    class ContainedClass1{

    }

    class ContainedClass2{

    }

}
```

This way they are tied to an instance of `ContainerClass` and cannot be created without an instance of the same. You can make them private, then they can only be created within the class

Comment: can u please elaborate or give figurative examples.

Comment: @qualtar It is basically the same answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, what you want is an inner class. Essentially to create an inner class you write class A inside class B.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class A as static inner class of B and keep the constructor of A as private. Then only B can use this constructor.

Some links for reference:

[scope of private constructor in Nested Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542193/scope-of-private-constructor-in-nested-class)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use classLoaders to determine if A class loaded from B or not