# Java access modifiers, nested classes

Tags: java

The following constellation:

```
public class AccessModifierTest {

  private static class Super {
    private int n = 3;

    private Super() {}

    private void setN(int n) {
      this.n = n;
    }
  }

  private static class Sub extends Super {
    private Sub() {
      super(); // invoking private ctor is permitted
      // setN(5); but invoking private method is not permitted, why?
      // super.setN(5); this is fine too
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Super superInstance = new Sub();
  }

}
```

The private ctor of Sub is allowed to invoke the private ctor of Super.

Why this is ok, is answered here:
[scope of private constructor in Nested Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542193/scope-of-private-constructor-in-nested-class)

Because of this, shouldn't it be also fine to invoke the private method setN in the ctor of Sub?

Why is this not legal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like the superclass constructor, `setN` is perfectly *accessible* in `Sub`. This is because, as your linked Q&A explained, `private` members declared in an inner class are accessible everywhere as long as you are inside the top-level class. So the problem is somewhere else.

If you are using IntelliJ, the error message it gives is "`setN` has private access...", which is more useful and lets you fix the error immediately (and `setN` being private also plays a role as you will see). But `javac`'s error message, "cannot find symbol `setN`", shows that **this isn't actually about accessibility**, and that the compiler can't actually find `setN`.

According to the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.7.1), a simple method name like `setN`

> consists of a single UnqualifiedMethodIdentifier which specifies the name of the method to be invoked. The rules of method invocation require that the UnqualifiedMethodIdentifier denotes a method that is in scope at the point of the method invocation.

`setN` is actually not in scope in the constructor of `Sub`. The scope of `setN` is only `Super`. See also [Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) in the spec.

But doesn't `Sub` inherit `setN` from `Super`? Well, it doesn't. `private` members are not inherited. See [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) for the conditions for inheritance.

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass type D all concrete
> methods m (both static and instance) for which all of the following
> are true:
>
> - m is a member of D.
> - m is public, protected, or declared with package access in the same
>   package as C.
> - No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature
>   (§8.4.2) of the signature of m as a member of D.

If you use another form (instead of a simple name) to refer to `Super.setN`, like `super.setN(5);`, or  `((Super)this).setN(5);` then it can compile just fine.

For why these work, see the [compile-time step 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) of processing a method call, where the compiler determines in which type it should search for a method declaration. If the type to search is `Super`, then it would compile, because `Super` actually has the `setN` method, whereas `Sub` does not inherit it from `Super`, so does not have it as a member.

Note that constructor calls and method calls are treated completely separately by the language spec and they have [completely different rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1). The `super();` syntax is essentially "hardcoded" into the language - there is no "scope" or "names" of a constructor or anything like that. The constructor just has to be accessible for you to call it.

Comment: thank you very much for clarification and the spec links!
Eclipse also gives a "not visible error", which is a bit confusing. 
I try to keep jls 8.4.8 in mind. In simple words: private methods are not inherited.
Nevertheless they are callable by using "super" in case of nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler understands the scope of the class Super is within the AccessModifierTest, but compiler does not know a callee method of any class without the reference. This is how oop based languages are designed to work. The main benefit is that compiler can remove the method call ambiguity through this.

So when a private constructor is called within a class scope compiler understands where it is coming from, but any other method requires the object reference to access.

to make your code work you need to use the reference super.setN(5) to make it work.